# Type signature of a Rust HashMap of a function

Tags: types, compiler-errors, rust

I create a HashMap which maps strings to functions of type `Vec<Expression> -> Expression`, where `Expression` is a type I have defined. The code in question is:

```
let functions: HashMap<_, _> = vec!(("+", Box::new(plus))).into_iter().collect();
```

If I let Rust infer the type for me, as in the code above, it compiles and runs fine, as in the code above. However, if I try to specify the type, it doesn't compile:

```
let functions: HashMap<&str, Box<Fn(Vec<Expression>) -> Expression>> =
    vec!(("+", Box::new(plus))).into_iter().collect();
```

The compiler error message isn't very helpful:

```
let functions: HashMap<&str, Box<Fn(Vec<Expression>) -> Expression>> = vec!(("+", Box::new(plus))).into_iter().collect();
^^^^^^^ a collection of type `std::collections::HashMap<&str, std::boxed::Box<std::ops::Fn(std::vec::Vec<Expression>) -> Expression>>` cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type `(&str, std::boxed::Box<fn(std::vec::Vec<Expression>) -> Expression {plus}>)`
```

What is the actual type of this `HashMap`?

Comment: It seems my google-fu is really weak as I could have sworn there was a duplicate for this :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look closely at the difference you will have your answer, although it can be puzzling.

I expect that `plus` has been declared as:

```
fn plus(v: Vec<Expression>) -> Expression;
```

In this case, the type of `plus` is `fn(Vec<Expression>) -> Expression {plus}`, and is actually a [Voldemort Type](https://wiki.dlang.org/Voldemort_types): it cannot be named.

Most notably, it differs from an eventual `fn(Vec<Expression>) -> Expression {multiply}`.

Those two types can be coerced into a bare `fn(Vec<Expression>) -> Expression` (without the `{plus}`/`{multiply}` denomination).

And this latter type can be transformed into a `Fn(Vec<Expression>) -> Expression`, which is a trait for any callable which do not modify their environments (such as the closure `|v: Vec<Expression>| v[0].clone()`).

---

The problem, however, is that while `fn(a) -> b {plus}` can be transformed into `fn(a) -> b` which can be transformed into `Fn(a) -> b`... the transformation requires *a change of memory representation*. This is because:

- `fn(a) -> b {plus}` is a zero-sized type,
- `fn(a) -> b` is a pointer to function,
- `Box<Fn(a) -> b>` is a boxed **trait object** which generally means both a virtual pointer *and* a data pointer.

And therefore the type ascription doesn't work, because it can only perform cost-free coercions.

---

The solution is to perform the transformation before it's too late:

```
// Not strictly necessary, but it does make code shorter.
type FnExpr = Box<Fn(Vec<Expression>) -> Expression>;

let functions: HashMap<_, _> =
    vec!(("+", Box::new(plus) as FnExpr)).into_iter().collect();
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Or maybe you'd rather keep unboxed functions:

```
// Simple functions only
type FnExpr = fn(Vec<Expression>) -> Expression;

let functions: HashMap<_, _> =
    vec!(("+", plus as FnExpr)).into_iter().collect();
```

Comment: BTW, `fn(A) -> B {plus}` is not a pointer. [It is zero-sized.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=0ad4ee6d789294e3af47d0a71dc74940&version=stable)

Comment: @red75prime: Oh right, I always forget about this neat thing!

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed and comprehensive answer. This perfectly answers my question.

Answer (score 2):

The relevant parts of error message are `Box<std::ops::Fn ...  >` and `Box<fn ... {plus}>`. The first is a boxed `Fn` trait object. The second is a boxed function `plus`. Note that it isn't a boxed pointer to a function, which would be `Box<fn ...>` with no `{plus}` part. It is the unique and unnameable type of the function `plus` itself.

That is you cannot write real type of this `HashMap`, as the type it contains is unnameable. It's not a big deal though, you can only put `plus` function into it.

The following code gives compilation error

```
let functions: HashMap<_, _> =
    vec![("+", Box::new(plus)), 
         ("-", Box::new(minus))].into_iter().collect();
                        ^^^^^ expected fn item, found a different fn item
```

This works, but it is useless

```
let functions: HashMap<_, _> =
    vec![("+", Box::new(plus)), 
         ("-", Box::new(plus))].into_iter().collect();
```

One possible solution is to convert first element of a vector into the required type.

```
type BoxedFn = Box<Fn(Vec<Expression>) -> Expression>;

let functions: HashMap<&str, BoxedFn> =
    vec![("+", Box::new(plus) as BoxedFn),
         ("_", Box::new(minus))].into_iter().collect();
```

Another one is type ascription of intermediate variable.

```
type BoxedFn = Box<Fn(Vec<Expression>) -> Expression>;

let v: Vec<(_, BoxedFn)> = vec![("+", Box::new(plus)), ("_", Box::new(minus))];
let functions: HashMap<&str, BoxedFn> = v.into_iter().collect();
```