# Is it possible to pass an Arc<RwLock<&Fn()>> to a function without using a type parameter?

Tags: reference, rust, trait-objects

I have to pass a `Arc<RwLock<&Fn()>>` to a function:

```
use std::sync::{Arc, RwLock};

fn main() {
    let closure = || println!("Hello World");
    let wrapped_closure = Arc::new(RwLock::new(&closure));
    execute(wrapped_closure);
}

fn execute(f: Arc<RwLock<&Fn()>>) {
    let rw_lock_read_guard = f.read().unwrap();
    (rw_lock_read_guard)()
}
```

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=5261ddc7a8ec8efc064a4a6a5f5757e1)

Compilation fails with the error message:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:6:13
  |
6 |     execute(wrapped_closure);
  |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected trait std::ops::Fn, found closure
  |
  = note: expected type `std::sync::Arc<std::sync::RwLock<&std::ops::Fn()>>`
             found type `std::sync::Arc<std::sync::RwLock<&[closure@src/main.rs:4:19: 4:45]>>`
```

Isn't the closure an `Fn`?

I have tried:

- Replacing the `Arc<RwLock>` with a reference (resulting in `&&Fn()`). This only works when you remove one ampersand in the function signature of `execute()`, but that doesn't really help me, because for reasons I don't want to explain here, I need those wrappers. [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=a42a8fa01119b358668b37757d108e28)
- Moving the `Fn()` in the `execute()` function signature into a where clause:

  ```
  fn execute(f: Arc<RwLock<&F>>) where F: Fn() { /* ... */ }
  ```

  That also works, **but** I cannot use a where clause either (because I would need it in a struct, but in structs there are no where clauses).
- Combining the two previous ideas: Passing a `Arc<RwLock<&&Fn()>>` and removing one ampersand in the function signature. That would be what I need, but it also fails.
- Casting `wrapped_closure` into an `Arc<RwLock<&Fn()>>` (this was the solution to a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45159414/type-signature-of-a-rust-hashmap-of-a-function)). This fails as it's a "non-primitive cast"

Is it possible to pass an `Arc<RwLock<&Fn()>>` in Rust without adding a type parameter and a where clause? If yes, how?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I believe your question is answered by the answers of [https://stackoverflow.com/q/45159414/155423](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45159414/155423). TL;DR: `Box::new(&closure as &Fn())`. If you disagree, please [edit] your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: **`&closure as &Fn()`**, not the entire type.

Comment: @Shepmaster. Okay, it works. But now I am passing just the &Fn() although execute() needs all the wrappers around it as well. Or did I misunderstand something?

Comment: `let wrapped_closure = Arc::new(RwLock::new(&closure as &Fn()));`

Comment: @Shepmaster *facepalm* I think it works now. Thanks a lot for the patience

Comment: I think the `<F>` was an incidental mistake, not part of the problem, so I removed it and edited the title to be more clear about the issue since I really don't think it's about `where` clauses at all. If you don't think my edits are true to the spirit of the original question, please feel free to edit it back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is by Shepmaster and taken from the comments.

The trick is to cast the closure reference to a `&Fn`, replacing `Arc::new(RwLock::new(&closure))` with `Arc::new(RwLock::new(`**`&closure as &Fn()`**`))`.